# comparing objects pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this function to test if two references are to the same object. But I keep getting the error invalid operands to binary expression.

```
bool Collider::remove(Actor &actor){

    for(int x=0; x< this->stack.size(); x++){
        if( actor == this->stack[x]){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

this is how I define the variable stack

```
vector<Actor*> stack;
```

I sort of understand the problem but can`t quite get the syntax correct.
Actually am I even comparing objects here, no right? It would seem I am actually testing if these two pointers point to the same place?

Comment: `actor` isn't a pointer, it's a reference.

Comment: I'm going to hate myself for this, `if (&actor == this->stack[x])`

Comment: @JamesAndino No. you can't have arrays or pointers *to* references.

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out and it scares me also.

Comment: You also do not need the this pointer in methods `this->stack` is the same as just `stack`

Comment: You may also want to choose a different name than `stack`, which is one of the predefined container types in the `std` namespace.

Comment: I would but I am a javascript programmer @ <3 so I need my code to be as scary as possible.

Comment: @WhozCraig it should be safe as long as there are no `using namespace std` in his code. But I guess its better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: is there a simple way to have a collection of dynamically sized objects that are referenced. I can see why using pointers like this is goofy.

Comment: @JamesAndino what exactly are you trying to do? Should collide return true only if two pointers point to the same location or should it return true if the object contained at that location is the same for two pointers?

Answer (score 1):

`actor` is an object, and it's being passed by-reference; it is *not* a pointer. So what you must to do is compare the address of `actor` to the pointer. We do this by using the unary `&` operator:

```
if (&actor == this->stack[x])
```

Using `==` on the actual `actor` object is invalid unless it has a sufficient overload of `operator==`. Otherwise you get the error you stated earlier.

Comment: `actor` isn't really an object, it's a reference to another object. It's more like an alias.